# How to handle different models returned by a single Web API call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, autorest

I am consuming an API that provides this operation:

```
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = nameof(GetUsers))]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "Result", typeof(List<UserModel>))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<UserModel>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorModel), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(string tenantId, int departmentId)
{
    // Magically queries the users and returns OK or detect something is wrong and returns BadRequest
    ...
}
```

This call can return a list of `UserModel` if everything is fine or an `ErrorModel` if the request is wrong.

Using `swagger` and `autorest`, I get an autogenerated client that has this method returning an object:

```
 public async Task<HttpOperationResponse<object>> GetUsersWithHttpMessagesAsync(string tenantId, int departmentId, string commitReference = default(string), Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
   ...
}
```

In that method, the algorithm checks for the status code. If the status code is 200, then it builds a list of `UserModel`:

```
    // Deserialize Response
    if ((int)_statusCode == 200)
    {
        _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            _result.Body = SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserModel>>(_responseContent, DeserializationSettings);
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            _httpRequest.Dispose();
            if (_httpResponse != null)
            {
                _httpResponse.Dispose();
            }
            throw new SerializationException("Unable to deserialize the response.", _responseContent, ex);
        }
   }
```

However, if the status code is 400, then an instance of `ErrorModel` is being built:

```
if ((int)_statusCode == 404)
{
    _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        _result.Body = SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorModel>(_responseContent, DeserializationSettings);
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        _httpRequest.Dispose();
        if (_httpResponse != null)
        {
            _httpResponse.Dispose();
        }
        throw new SerializationException("Unable to deserialize the response.", _responseContent, ex);
    }
}
```

So anytime I am using this method, I have to check for the type of the object returned to find out if I have a list of `UserModel` or an `ErrorModel`.

I have to do something like this when I call the autogenerated client:

```
object result = await client.GetUserAsync(tenantId, departmentId);

switch (result)
{
    case List<UserModel> userModels:
        // Handle the users.
    case ErrorModel errorModel:
        // Handle the error.
}
```

This pushes any type safety checks at the runtime instead of compile-time which in turn can lead to bugs.

**Question**

How can I handle this situation in C# without having to rely on runtime type checks?

Comment: This is a bit opinionated, hard to answer objectively. In my *opinion* an API should declare only a single response type. For things like a 400 Bad Request, I'd document that in case of a bad request, this is the common model for all actions.

Comment: @juunas I agree it is in the grey zone. I will adjust the question to push more towards the recommended / best practice.

Comment: In general, I would never return different models from the same call; 
with only one exception, that is the error; but that is okay in my eyes, because the http status code clearly differentiates them; in case of `http 20x` you promise the `UserModel`, in all other cases the `ErrorModel`.
If the swagger file clearly reflects that fact, that sould be perfectly fine;

Comment: Consider an HTTP request with an `Accept` header of `Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8`. So clearly, an HTTP endpoint returning different things is already a normal part of usage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It just means that it accepts different format of what I would guess is the same model. This does not cause clients to go through hoops to find out what the model is :) In my case, the client would just send a request with `application/json`... as long as it is the same model.

Comment: I would suggest to create generic `MyApiResponse`, which incorporates generic information about error (in case it's existence) and some generic data. Henceforth, you will always return the same answer.